# libGDX lags are causing shifts

Tags: time, libgdx, lag, pause

I made a games where different items(rectangles with textures) should be created regularly. These Items are always moving left (like [this](http://cases.goaggro.com/)) so it should look like this:
[image: Without lags]

But if it's lagging or if I click on the menu bar (where the close button etc. is)
and the game "pauses" the items aren't spawning regularly so it looks like this:
[image: With lags]

This is obstructing the gameplay so I want to fix this.
This is the part where I spawn the items:

```
    public void renderMain(){

        timeState += delta;
        if (timeState >= 0.32f) {
            timeState = 0f; 
            Item.spawnitem();
        }
...
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to separate game logic from the render speed so your game logic updates at a fixed rate independent of render rate. http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: Thank You! I separated render and update things and I set delta to 1/60 in update;